# How to configure Metronic theme to work with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, metronic

I have purchased & downloaded the v8.0.19 [Metronic](https://themeforest.net/item/metronic-responsive-admin-dashboard-template/4021469) theme.
I am working with the HTML theme.
I am using Rails 6 and I would like to understand how I should integrate the theme with Rails framework. Specifically,

1. There is dist/ and src/ folders. Which one should I use within my rails code? and how?
2. Since rails uses webpacker and asset pipeline for front-end assets, how do I configure the Metronic HTML theme to work with rails. Metronic has gulp and webpack build tools. How do I customize it to work with Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering My Own question here in case anyone struggles with the same problem.
Please see my gist in GitHub
https://gist.github.com/kamalptw/cad9cc02dc7d483aaa8f2e05ed2b8fc6